# Any free alternative to Robohelp?

Tags: open-source, chm, robohelp, help-authoring

Any free alternative to Robohelp?  Prefer open source

Need some sort of online help authoring tool for an open source project.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help_authoring_tool#Common_Help_Authoring_Tools

Answer (score 4):

Check out this [list of free help authoring tools](http://www.thefreecountry.com/programming/helpauthoring.shtml), bound to be something useful there.

Answer (score 4):

Just remembered: depending on what you want to do, you can use doxygen (www.doxygen.org) or the free help tool from http://www.vizacc.com/.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with http://www.vizacc.com/ (they just have a forum left), however you can download HelpMaker (the latest I'm aware of is 7.4.4) by simply googling it (e.g. from Softpedia - http://www.softpedia.com/get/Authoring-tools/Help-e-book-creators/HelpMaker.shtml)

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/helpmaker/?source=typ_redirect

Answer (score 3):

I like [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/).

You write your documentation using a plain text markup format, [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html).

Sphinx can create HTML, Windows HTML help and PDF (via Latex).

I have created end-user documentation for two projects using Sphinx, and have also used it to document a couple of Python packages (Sphinx has a lot of features around extracting documentation from Python modules, it was originally created to write the Python documentation).

It is very easy to get started, and you get professional-looking documentation with a minimal effort.

If you are used to the WYSIWYG way of text editing, using a plain-text markup format might take some getting used to. But I believe it will be worth the effort.

I also have some experience with DocBook (one of the end-user documentation projects mentioned was a DocBook-to-Sphinx migration). I prefer Sphinx over Docbook: Plain text is more pleasant to work with than XML, Sphinx has a simpler toolchain.

See also:

- [List of projects using Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/examples.html).
- [PDF example](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/sphinx.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to make just CHM or other output formats too?

Take a look at DocBook. You can make (from one source file) pdf, html and chm - and some others, too. I've used it in the past but it's not very easy or convenient to use. If you only want to output chm (and need to use a free solution), see if you can get away with using the htmlhelp workshop (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=00535334-c8a6-452f-9aa0-d597d16580cc&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to build .chm based help, try [**chm-build**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/chm-build/)

Comment: The project is in pre-alpha stage. Have you used it yourself?